# Use a value bound to an identifier in f# pattern?

Tags: f#

I want a recursive function in F# with a signature of:  string * int * char -> int, 
One terminating pattern is an empty string  | ("", i, c) -> 0, 
A second should be i = String.length s {when s is the first item in the triple}

```
    let rec myf (s, i, c) =
      let lens = String.length s in
         match s, i, c with
         | "", i,   c -> 0
         | s, lens, c -> 0
         | s, i,    c -> (if s.[i] = c then 1 else 0) + myf(s, i+1, c)
```

This does not work because the 3rd pattern is never matched, presumably because lens in the 2nd pattern is treated as a wildcard. Is it possible to use a symbol with a value bound to it in a pattern, with a pattern matching against only that value?

PS: myf counts the occurrences of c in s at an index >= i

Answer (score 4):

You need to add a guard:

```
let rec myf (s, i, c) =
    match s, i, c with
    | "", i,   c -> 0
    | s, i, c when s.Length = i -> 0
    | s, i,    c -> (if s.[i] = c then 1 else 0) + myf(s, i+1, c)
```